# Vue JS 2 table viewing complete objects instead of values

Tags: javascript, json, html-table, vuejs2

I'm still pretty new to Vue JS 2. I am building a dynamic table, where the number of columns (and column titles) will fluctuate depending on the array that's assigned to it. This would mean I can't do something like this

```
<td>{{assignments.name}}</td>
<td>{{assignments.id}}</td>
<td>{{assignments.location}}</td>
```

because the data will change and not always match up accordingly. I'm pulling from hard-coded JSON until I have my API set up:

```
[
{
  "Name": "Jennison",
  "ID": 879456,
  "Location": "Carotsville"
},
{
  "Name": "Cordan",
  "ID": 547932,
  "Location": "Paperville"
},
{
  "Name": "Sir Mac",
  "ID": 423971,
  "Location": "Hammerville"
},
{
  "Name": "Pat",
  "ID": 984123,
  "Location": "Isenville"
}
]
```

Below is the markup that I'm struggling with. Instead of grabbing each of the values, it's grabbing each of the objects. What would I need to do to have it grab the values instead, in order to properly populate the table?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-for="(value, key) in assignmentsHardcoded[0]" v-bind:key="value">{{key}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="assignments in assignmentsHardcoded" v-bind:key="assignments.id">{{ assignments }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the outcome: 
[image]

What would I need to do to have it grab the values instead, in order to properly populate the table?

Comment: I'd probably expose a `computed` property of an array of keys, then you can iterate over *that*. You want to loop over `assignmentsHardcoded` for the `tr`s, then  the key array for the `td`s.

Comment: @jonrsharpe a computed property would be a good idea, but not really needed as you can manage the same outcome without the computed property, but essentially the same template structure. See my answer for more info

Comment: @Derek object order isn't guaranteed, you won't necessarily get the right values in the right columns

Comment: @jonrsharpe - even if that were an issue, OP could loop through the first element of the array's attributes and use them, still eliminating the need for a computed property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This should do the trick:**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th 
        v-if="assignmentsHardcoded.length" 
        v-for="(value, key) in assignmentsHardcoded.find(a=>true)" 
        :key="value">
        {{key}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(assignment, i) in assignmentsHardcoded" :key="'a-'+i">
      <td v-for="attr in assignment">{{ attr }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem you were having is that you were looping through on a `td` which would only work if you expected all the data to be displayed on a single row.

Considering that is usually not the case, it makes sense to lift the  `v-for` up to the `<tr>` tag so we can use it in our `v-for` on our `<td>`'s since the attributes can differ and we don't want stuck in a place where we are hard-coding the data structure.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but as I mentioned, the arrays will fluctuate. I'm trying to make this dynamic. It won't always be Name, ID, and Location. I need it to pull the values whatever they may be without pre-defining them.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! It didn't even occur to me that I could do that, but it makes sense to me now.

Comment: @PorterLyman glad I could help! Sorry, I must have initially missed the portion about not being able to use the correct names